# I am not able to open this .a file and don't know how to use it

Tags: c++

Here is the link: https://github.com/eyetribe

I tried to run this `tet-cpp-client` and in the output I am getting `Gazeapilib.a` file, and when I am trying to open it, it's giving me error that I can't open that file.

I want to know how to open this file, and what is the data of this file and how it can be used further in any program? I have not much knowledge about it so please help me to solve this error.

I am running this program in Ubuntu using cmake software.

Answer (score 3):

The .a file is a library file which contains the definitions of the functions in the library that you compiled. It is not a standalone program and must be linked with other code to make a program. You must pass this library file to the linker after building your program.